# .NET 5 Blazor HttpClient BaseAddressAuthorizationMessageHandler not found

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-webassembly, .net-5

I am trying to add Authentication to my .NET 5 Blazor WASM application using [this article](https://chrissainty.com/securing-your-blazor-apps-authentication-with-clientside-blazor-using-webapi-aspnet-core-identity/) and I am getting an error

`Unhandled exception rendering component: No service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.BaseAddressAuthorizationMessageHandler' has been registered.`

I downloaded the sample from the git [here](https://github.com/chrissainty/AuthenticationWithClientSideBlazor), ran it and everything worked, then I noticed that the sample was done in .NET 3 and when I updated it to run on .NET 5 the same error is creeping up. In my `Program.cs` I registered the `HttpClient` and the `BaseAddressAuthorizationMessageHandler` like so

```
  public static async Task Main(string[] args)
  {
     var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
     builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("app");

     builder.Services.AddHttpClient("ServerAPI",
        client => client.BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress))
     .AddHttpMessageHandler<BaseAddressAuthorizationMessageHandler>();

     builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => sp.GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>()
         .CreateClient("ServerAPI"));

     builder.Services.AddBlazoredLocalStorage();
     builder.Services.AddAuthorizationCore();
     builder.Services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, ApiAuthenticationStateProvider>();
     builder.Services.AddScoped<IAuthService, AuthService>();

     await builder.Build().RunAsync();
  }
```

I think this is a false error, as you can see I am adding the `BaseAddressAuthorizationMessageHandler` to the client just as it shows [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/additional-scenarios?view=aspnetcore-5.0), is there something I am missing? Is there a namespace I need to import or is there another part of the configuration missing? Breakpoints don't seem to work in the client's `Program.cs` and I don't see any other errors that could explain this.

Answer (score 4):

This was a fairly easy fix once I figured out what was going on, when the authorization is setup like this apparently you don't need to add the `BaseAddressAuthorizationMessageHandler` to the client since this example is manually setting the HTTP request headers via the `AuthService`

```
  public static async Task Main(string[] args)
  {
     var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
     builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("app");

     builder.Services.AddHttpClient("ServerAPI",
        client => client.BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress));

     builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => sp.GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>()
         .CreateClient("ServerAPI"));

     builder.Services.AddBlazoredLocalStorage();
     builder.Services.AddAuthorizationCore();
     builder.Services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, ApiAuthenticationStateProvider>();
     builder.Services.AddScoped<IAuthService, AuthService>();

     await builder.Build().RunAsync();
  }
```